How to apply function type to generator?
I have the following generator function:
async function * filterIterable (iter, predicate) {
  let i = 0
  for await (const val of iter) {
    if (predicate(val, i++)) {
      yield val
    }
  }
}

that I would like to type for the following two cases:
// type predicate
const nonNullable = <T>(val: T | undefined | null): val is T =>
  val !== undefined && val !== null

async function * gen1 () {
  yield 1
  yield 2
  yield 3
}

async function * gen2 () {
  yield 1
  yield undefined
  yield 3
}

const it1 = filterIterable(gen1(), n => n % 2 === 0)
const it2 = filterIterable(gen2(), nonNullable) // should be AsyncIterable<1 | 2>

I came up with this interface:
interface FilterIterable {
  <T> (
    iter: AsyncIterable<T>,
    predicate: (val: T, index: number) => boolean,
  ): AsyncIterable<T>;
  <T, S extends T> (
    iter: AsyncIterable<T>,
    predicate: (val: T, index: number) => val is S,
  ): AsyncIterable<S>;
}

which I could apply to a function expression, but apparently not to a function declaration per How to apply a function type to a function declaration. Is this not what the generator is?

Not quite, the output is AsyncGenerator, not AsyncIterable. Do you need to "apply" a type? Why not just overload the function directly as shown in this playground link? Does that meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz oh, I forgot you could do multiple function filterIterable declarations and they would be merged. That's great, thanks!

btw. I'm using AsyncIterable instead of AsyncGenerator just because it's a simpler type and I might actually change the implementation later to not be a generator. Actually, I might use AsyncIterator instead. Since that's the prototyp that will get the helper methods added.

@mb21 shameless plug https://github.com/jasmith79/sequable

So you want filterIterable() to be an overloaded function with multiple call signatures. While it's true that you can't currently directly annotate a function as requested in microsoft/TypeScript#22063, you could just use regular overload syntax and declare the call signatures before the implementation:
// call signatures
function filterIterable<T, S extends T>(
  iter: AsyncIterable<T>, predicate: (val: T, index: number) => val is S
): AsyncIterable<S>;
function filterIterable<T>(
  iter: AsyncIterable<T>, predicate: (val: T, index: number) => boolean
): AsyncIterable<T>;

// implementation
async function* filterIterable<T>(
  iter: AsyncIterable<T>, predicate: (val: T, index: number) => boolean
) {
  let i = 0
  for await (const val of iter) {
    if (predicate(val, i++)) {
      yield val
    }
  }
}

This should now work as you intended:
async function foo() {
  const it1 = filterIterable(gen1(), n => n % 2 === 0)
  for await (const x of it1) {
    //             ^? const x: 1 | 2 | 3
    console.log(x.toFixed(2))
  }
  const it2 = filterIterable(gen2(), nonNullable) 
  for await (const y of it2) {
    //             ^? const y: 1 | 3
    console.log(y.toFixed(3))    
  }
}

Playground link to code

Thanks! Interestingly, the order of the call signatures matters...
